# cakephp array's and find statement

Tags: sql, cakephp, find

I have two find statements and need the results of one find statement to use in the second find statement however the two methods I have tried to use have come back with errors

here is the first find statement, it lists the sender_id's

```
$sender=$this->Invoice->Find('list', array('fields'=>('sender_id')));
```

here is the second find statement, it takes that list of `sender_id`'s and returns the corresponding `company_name`

```
$senderName=$this->Account->Find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
        $sender=>'account.id')));
```

this returns the right information however returns this error `Warning (2): Illegal offset type [APP\Controller\InvoicesController.php, line 185]`

so i tried doing it this way

```
$senderName=$this->Account->Find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
        'id'=>$sender['Invoice']['sender_id'])));
```

and get an undefined index on invoice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$senderName=$this->Account->Find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Account.id' => array_values($sender),
        ),
));
```

The key is the field and the value is, well, the value(s).